# Checkboxes in a range

Tags: excel, checkbox

I have a sheet with checkboxes and names. I need one specific cell to show only the value of the cell related to the checkbox. For example.

when I press the checkbox for Lorena the cell A1 shows Lorena, if I check the one for Ricardo the cell A1 must show Ricardo. Is there any way to do it? I need to work with a range of 15 records.

Thank you!

Comment: I suggest you to use option button rather than check box because check box is for multi-select. I can help to use option buttons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An option button is going to work much better in this situation since it sounds like the there will only be one selected value, a collection of checkboxes won't work. The option button will ensure that only one value is selected at any time. I have an example set of code below for a set of three and attached images of it working. In order to achieve 15 records, it would simply be a matter of expanding from 3 to 15 option buttons.

In order to make this example work, simply add three option buttons and leave them with their default name. Then use the "Click" event that they have by default to trigger a function to post their caption into the cell A1. Make sure the option buttons have a caption of the name you want entered.

```
Option Explicit

Sub PrintName(name As String)
    Cells(1, 1).Value = name
End Sub

Private Sub OptionButton1_Click()
    PrintName OptionButton1.Caption
End Sub

Private Sub OptionButton2_Click()
    PrintName OptionButton2.Caption
End Sub

Private Sub OptionButton3_Click()
    PrintName OptionButton3.Caption
End Sub
```

Comment: Why not using `application.caller`? This way you could use one macro for all buttons...

Comment: Thanks both of you. I don't know how to use application.caller